# Inserting Value into many to many database using MVC asp.net not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have two tables Post and Keywords each post can have many keywords and each keyword can be used in many posts. Using entity framework I created the two tables and it automatically created the linked table KeyWordPost containing the two table primary keys. When I try to insert using the code below I keep getting a Nullreference exception during the insert.

```
public ActionResult Update(int? id, string title, string body, string       author, string keywords)
    {
        if (!IsAdmin)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        Post post = GetPost(id);
        post.Title = title;
        post.Body = body;
        post.Authorised = true;
        post.Author = "admin";



        keywords = keywords ?? string.Empty;
        string[] keynames = keywords.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);


        foreach (string keyname in keynames)
        {
            KeyWord kw = GetKeyWord(keyname);
            post.KeyWords.Add(kw);
        }   
        if (!id.HasValue) { 
            db.Posts.Add(post); } 

        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = post.Id });
    }

  private KeyWord GetKeyWord(string keyname)
    {
        return db.KeyWords.Where(x => x.Name == keyname).FirstOrDefault() ?? new KeyWord() { Name = keyname };
    }
```

Post table model

```
 public class Post
{

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
    public Boolean Authorised { get; set; }

    public string Author { get; set; }


    public ICollection<KeyWord> KeyWords { get; set; }


}
```

Keyword model

```
public class KeyWord
{

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }


}
```

Comment: What are the details of the exception? And why do you have all those parameters in you method instead of just binding to the model?

Comment: Can we see your mappings ?

Comment: {"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."} is the error message. Using the parameters as copying a tutorial once I have it working I will change it to use the Model. Having real problems with the many to many relationship and there seems to be loads of info on how to set them up but none on how to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added in extra line  and it seems to have fixed itself

```
 foreach (var keynum in keynames)
        {
            KeyWord KeytoAdd = db.KeyWords.Find(int.Parse(keynum));

            post.KeyWords = new List<KeyWord>();

            post.KeyWords.Add(KeytoAdd);

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if your `id` is not actually null. This is the only one field that you are not setting by yourself in model Post. Also you are adding a new keyword to post, but do you actually insert in database something? `db.Posts.Add(post)`  will add a new row in post table only but not in keyword. I guess there is some foreign key relationship between those 2 tables and you are not fullfilling it properly. Instead of `post.keywords.Add(kw)` you might want to use `db.KeyWords.Add(kw)`

2nd thing is that db.Table_Name supports method Find. `db.Posts.Find(id)` for example. You can try use that instead of custom methods.

3rd thing is that I suggest 1 to * relationship in database instead * to * like in your case.

Comment: Thanks i was using the custom method as trying to follow a tutorial I know its the not the best way to do it so will change. The Id is not null well at least it isn't when I debugging will put in an extra check thanks.